# Ui imageview picker image disappears when navigating from page

Tags: ios, ios5, uiimageview

I have a Ui image view that selects a photo form cameraroll to display in my app, when I move away form the page it disappears.  Any way to hold onto it when page is navigated away from?

xcode 4.3 Thanks

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
imageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];




- (IBAction)getPhoto:(id)sender {



UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;

if((UIButton *) sender == choosePhotoBtn) {
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
}

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```